# Excel VBA - dynamic formula autofill

Tags: excel, vba

[as i described below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI0pA.png) i am thinking if excel vba can create a marco that when i see variables "A","B" or "C", they can apply a formulas that i had written on another tablets say: The formulas are as below

```
'for -A = B*0.5
'for -B = B
'for -C = A+B
```

given that i have 50+ variables on hands.

Comment: What do you mean variables?  Values in a cell or something within another part of the VBA code?

Comment: Your question is not at all clear.

Comment: like a configuration tab contains many variables with a specific forumlas. how can i use vba to automatically apply those forumlas in another worksheet if i have that variables again

Comment: Please, attach source data, excel sheet picture or etc that you will use for calculation. What do you want to have? A button or a custom formula. Can you explain. You see "A","B" or "C", then what do you do? Step by step.

Comment: Hi alexey, i have attached a picture which might give you more info.